# OBIEE Webservice for SOA

Tags: obiee

I am trying to get the web services for SOA to work. I am doing what oracle says, but i am still getting error 500 with the following error:

```
WatchData: MESSAGE = [ServletContext@1374343816[app:biwssoa module:biservices path:null spec-version:3.1 version:12.1.3]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to contact BI Presentation Server due to: Could not access the session service.
        at oracle.bi.ws.activeobjects.inspection.BiWsilServlet.doInspectionAction(BiWsilServlet.java:183)
        at oracle.bi.ws.activeobjects.inspection.BiWsilServlet.doGet(BiWsilServlet.java:137)
```

I added wsil.browsing credential and used the weblogic login in the enterprise manager. Didnt work.

Then i tried adding wss_username_token_policy.xml to

> /app/oracle/fmw12213/user_projects/domains/bi/config/fmwconfig/biinstances/coreapplication/

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oracle-webservice-clients>
<webservice-client>
<port-info>
<policy-references>
<policy-reference uri="oracle/log_policy" category="management"/>
<policy-reference uri="oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy" category="security"/>
</policy-references>
</port-info>
</webservice-client>
</oracle-webservice-clients>
```

And editing my ActionFrameworkConfig.xml in

> /app/oracle/fmw12213/user_projects/domains/bi/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/actions/

from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<obi-action-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="afconfig.xsd">
    <aliases/>
    <registries/>
    <content-types>
        <content-type>
            <typename>webservices</typename>
            <displayname>Web Services and BPEL Processes</displayname>
            <actionType>WebServiceActionType</actionType>
        </content-type>
        <content-type>
            <typename>misc</typename>
            <displayname>Mixed Services</displayname>
            <actionType>URLActionType</actionType>
        </content-type>
    </content-types>
    <accounts/>
    <policies/>
</obi-action-config>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<obi-action-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="afconfig.xsd">
    <aliases/>
    <registries>
        <registry>
            <id>reg1b</id>
            <name>BI EE Web Services for SOA</name>
            <content-type>webservices</content-type>
            <provider-class>oracle.bi.action.registry.wsil.WSILRegistry</provider-class>
            <description/>
            <location>
                <path>http://localhost:7033/biservices/inspection?wsil</path>
            </location>
            <service-access>
                <account>wsil.browsing</account>
                <policy>wss_username_token_policy</policy>
                <propagateIdentity>false</propagateIdentity>
            </service-access>
        </registry>
        <regestries>
            <content-types>
                <content-type>
                    <typename>webservices</typename>
                    <displayname>Web Services and BPEL Processes</displayname>
                    <actionType>WebServiceActionType</actionType>
                </content-type>
                <content-type>
                    <typename>misc</typename>
                    <displayname>Mixed Services</displayname>
                    <actionType>URLActionType</actionType>
                </content-type>
            </content-types>
            <accounts>
                <account>
                    <name>wsil.browsing</name>
                    <description>Account for BI WS for SOA</description>
                    <adminonly>false</adminonly>
                    <credentialkey>weblogic</credentialkey>
                </account>
            </accounts>
            <policies>
                <policy>
                    <name>wss_username_token_policy</name>
                    <policyfile>wss_username_token_policy.xml</policyfile>
                </policy>
            </policies>
        </obi-action-config>
```

Then i restarted bi server using domain_home/bitools/bin/stop.sh and start.sh. But its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your biservicesconfig.xml in

> /app/oracle/fmw12213/user_projects/domains/bi/config/fmwconfig/biinstances/coreapplication/

points to the same host:port as the file in ActionFrameworkConfig.xml. Also has the ending /analytics-ws/saw.dll

For me, that looked like this:

```
<server>http://localhost:7033/analytics-ws/saw.dll</server>
```